# How does std::cout print a std::string?

Tags: c++

Does `std::basic_ostream` have an overload of `operator <<` that accepts a `std::basic_string` object? I'm reading [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and there doesn't seem to be one listed.

Comment: It's in `<string>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: ... which makes sense, as that is where you would likely put an insertion override for a custom class *you* were designing; in its header file. The basic types and stream buffers are coupled with `basic_ostream`, however, as they should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are non-member operators defined in the `std` namespace. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

Comment: "globally" in namespace `std` :) ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string )

Comment: No, really, you should edit you answer. An `std::operator<<` is not the same as a global `operator<<`.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine you create your own class called `Car` which contains licence plates number, model/power of the engine, and bunch of other information. Now, imagine you want to provide nice way to print your car information into the file, or into the screen.

If you want to use `basic_ostream` overload, you have no luck, since there is no overload for your class defined. You may provide `print_into_ostream` method, or some other clever trick, but you've just realized that `std::string` also doesn't have the appropriate overload, and you still can do `cout << myStr;`. After a quick search, you find a solution that is applied into the `std::string`, and you can use it in your class like this:

```
class Car
{
    std::string licence_plate, engine;
public:
    // ... other here ...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Car& c);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Car& c)
{
    os << c.licence_plate << "-" << c.engine;
    return os;
}
```

And now you can use

```
cout << myCarObject << endl;
```

as with any built-in type.

`std::string` uses the same approach, and you can find documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an object of your `class A`, you overload `<< operator` like this:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, A &a)
{
    os << a.data_member;
}
```

In the same fashion in the `std namespace` there is an overloaded operator that prints object of class `string`.

Comment: The `A` should probably be `const`-qualified, and the function must return `os`.